# Highlight Non Match From List On Another Worksheet?

Tags: excel, vba, list, match, highlight

I am having trouble with getting the below VBA code to highlight the non-matches in column H on the sheets with the name "Revision". The master matching list is called "Materials" and it is column A there. Every time I run my current code, the whole column in the Revision sheet turns red. How do I get it to only highlight the non-match?

For example, say the "Materials" master sheet has the list Copper, and Steel. On the revision sheet it has Aluminum and Steel. How can the sheet only highlight the cell that says Aluminum in red?

Thanks.

```
Private Sub MaterialMatch()

Dim iRow As Long

Dim ws1 As Worksheet

Dim ws2 As Worksheet

Set ws2 = Worksheets("Materials")

Dim FoundRow As Variant

Dim lRowSource As Long

For Each ws1 In ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets
    
    If ws1.Name Like "Revision *" Then
    
    lRowSource = ws1.Cells(ws1.Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Row 'find last row in column A
        
        For iRow = 2 To lRowSource
          
            FoundRow = Application.Match(ws1.Cells(iRow, "H"), ws1.Columns("A"), 0)
        
            If IsError(FoundRow) Then
            
            ws1.Cells(iRow, "H").Interior.ColorIndex = 3
            
            End If
        
        Next iRow
        
    End If

Next ws1
    
End Sub
```

Comment: Is `ws2` supposed to be used inside the loop somewhere? I only see `ws1` used. Is the `ws1.Columns("A")` supposed to be `ws2.Columns("A")`?

Comment: Oh my goodness I didnt even realize... works now, thanks!